# My '06 Honda Civic headlights are malfunctioning

Tags: honda, civic, headlight, wiring

About a month ago I got a message on my dashboard notifying me that my Daytime Running Lights (DRL) were not working. A week later I noticed that both bulbs were broken inside the assembly. Now my headlights are not working. I have checked the fuses as well as the relay switch, and all seem to be ok. I am wondering if I need to replace all the wiring and if so, is that something that I should have done, or is it simple enough to do yourself?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the bulbs themselves to see if they are okay? If so, how did you verify?

Comment: I did not try replacing the bulbs because the DRL/High-beam bulbs both exploded on the same day. I was afraid that replacing them would only cause them to explode again. (I would have replaced it, if only one broke). The regular headlight bulbs were replaced a few months ago and are not broken like the other two are. Since all of the issues happened pretty close together it makes me think that it is an electrical issue?

Comment: While it does seem strange both light blowing around the same time, it's not unheard of for matching light bulbs to go out relatively close to one another. While it would suck to replace the bulbs, then find them blown up again, my bet is they won't. This is the cheapest and most simple fix to start with. You also know the bulbs will need to be replaced, anyway. Unless these are HID's, I'm not seeing as how any wiring issue would cause the problem. This is because regular light bulbs only get fed 12vdc power. If more amperage than normal were to get fed or used, the fuse would blow.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give it a try. So are you suggesting to replace all 4 bulbs (the 2 DRL, and the 2 regular headlights)?

Comment: All ***four*** bulbs blew? Yah, that's a might strange. Are you sure all of them have gone? Not sure about your Honda, but many vehicles use the main bulbs as DRLs, just only sending them 6v (or a lower voltage) when only being used as DRLs. Are you sure there isn't only two bulbs you'd be dealing with?

Comment: Only 2 bulbs (DRL) blew up (at the same time), and I didn't have high beams since then. Then 1 month or so later, the regular headlights both turned on, and then 3 seconds later, went out (at the same time) and never started working again.

Answer (score 1):

This is DaytimeDriverForNow. I couldn't log back in, but I wanted to update everyone. The problem was as simple as Paulster2 suggested. I replaced all 4 bulbs and they are working great so far! Thanks for the help, I'm relieved it was more simple than I thought. 
*I had a dull set of low beam headlights that I replaced a few months ago with something brighter, and I was told to keep the old set in the glovebox in case one goes out, and I didn't have time to replace it right away. I tried that set in the low beam slots before purchasing, in case that wasn't the problem. I put that dull set back in the glovebox for next time!

Comment: Thanks for the update!  If you're interested, you can probably recover your account using the email you used to sign up.